# Wordpress Header Image not showing alt text

Tags: wordpress

my theme is showing the alt text for the main header image as alt="". Even though I have added this in the media library etc.

I have found the PHP code in the header.PHP file as below. What do I need to change to manually put the alt text in?

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>"><img class="logo"  src="<?php echo esc_url(($site_logo)); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('sitename'); ?>" /></a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** use `sitename` in `<?php bloginfo('sitename'); ?>` for example you **can** use `<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>`

Below values what you can use.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/#possible-values-for-show